# Error handling pppd configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cellular, ppp

I have a computer, running ubuntu, that I want to be connected to the network at all times. It has a GSM modem connected to it via USB.

Is there some program available that monitors that the networking is working (by pinging some site(s)), and if not tries to fix the error by reseting the modem, reloading the USB drivers and perhaps by dropping the USB port's current (if possible) to force the modem to reset ?